# Plotly: draw legend while one column is chosen as Y

Tags: plotly

I'm wondering how to make plot.ly draw legend when only one column is chosen as Y (i'm talking about plot.ly REST API, but answer will cover their JS lib as well)

That's what plotly doing when two or more columns are chosen as Y:
[image]

But THAT's what happens when only one column is chosen as Y: its name goes not to legend, but to Y axis label. (only while on website — in API even Y axis label is empty)

[image]

So what should I do? Is there some sort of API option which will force plotly draw legend?

Answer (score 0):

Things may have changed since you asked but as for now, for Plotly JS, you shoud put `showlegend: true` in your layout.

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwwyZZ for an example.